# Java NIO - truncation of MappedByteBuffer

Tags: java, buffer, nio, memory-mapped-files, random-access

I am trying to use `MappedMemoryBuffer` to store/delete portions of byte from the file. Atm, I use the following approach: I have a position in the buffer marking the end of the data in the file (buffer is a bit bigger than the file to accommodate for appending). Each data chunk is of fixed length, let's say 200 bytes.

My first concern is "marking" of the end of the file. I can see two approaches to that:

1. Use some sort of a marker denoting the end of the actual data, while file size can be bigger (due to the fact that I keep it slightly bigger for appending reasons). This might be tricky to come up with some sort of byte sequence that would be unique.
2. Always make sure that the file we read in is "full" i.e. if that file is 2000 bytes, that means there are 10 messages in it and nothing more. That is even trickier I think, as we would have to constantly truncate the file size and with open memory buffer that is quite cumbersome (one cannot truncate the file size with open memory mapped file)

That's why I would lean more towards one, unless anyone knows a better approach?

Now, while appending is very simple, the deletion of **random** data chunk is not that straightforward. What I was thinking of doing was to shift the data to overwrite the deleted message. I simply move all the bytes to the right of message to the beginning of it.

In general, is that the right strategy, or would anyone suggest something else or improvements to the concept?

Comment: Shifting data in a file is a bad idea. If the order of your chunks is not important, you can move the last chunk to the position of the deleted one (given the fact that the chunks have equal size). Otherwise you should add a way to mark chunks as deleted and cleanup once you have significantly sparse chunks.

Comment: Is shifting bad due to performance reasons or sth more?

Comment: Mostly performance. But it also contradicts your intention to be safe for the case when your application is interrupted in between the operation.

Comment: Well, any marking taking more than one byte change would contradict that anyway - marking as deleted/shifting only one chunnk could still be interrupted right?

Comment: Also, when you say cleanup - that would require some byte shifting/truncation mechanism to actually get rid of "deleted" bytes, which I think comes back to the initial approach

Comment: Not exactly. You can overwrite the deleted bytes with the next new chunk. Only if you have a larger number of deletions without insertions it might be useful to compact the file. But in this case it’s a lot less data to transfer as you don’t need to shift deleted bytes.

Comment: A couple of points on this:

1. Even if you overwrite the chunk with the next, it is still not atomic i.e. it can fail at any point while writing the chunk, so it is not any better in that respect than the shift IMO

2. Compact the file - what do you mean by that? I still don't see how to do this without the shift. We have let's say 1000 bytes, bytes 20-40, 120-140 and 500-520 are marked as deleted. How would you compact without a move?

Comment: Compacting is similar to shifting. The difference is that in one case you have to copy a potentially large file content to accommodate a single deleted chunk in the other case you have to copy a few remaining chunks to accommodate lots of deletions. But that’s only a comment not an answer…

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom wrapper class over a `FileChannel` (or `File` or whatever, as long as you know it's your file) and make it provide mappings, or even write mappings by itself.

In this class, track the size. Make it implement `Closeable`. And when you `.close()` it, unmap everything and truncate/expand to the appropriate size.

Comment: The main concern with this is that the jvm can crash, and the file would be in an inconsistent state, so having a way to constantly mark the end of the file (with a marker as I described) seems a bit safer

Comment: Well, given the size of your files (rather small) you could also make this class write to a temporary file and rename to the original on `close()`